# Jenkins cancel build queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have multiple SCM jobs. Job A triggers Job B and Job C triggers Job D. While job C running if there is a checkin in Job A, after Job C is completed instead of triggering Job D , Job A is triggered and Job D is in queue. Once Job A is complete then Job D is triggered while Job B is in queue. Is this a bug ? would expect Job C to trigger Job D regardless of any SCM change in upstream job. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is expected, assuming that you only have one executor. First some terminology:

- **Queue**, this is the place where a build is before it's executed, usually because all executors are busy.
- **Triggered**, means that a a build of a job is added to the queue.
- **Executor**, Takes the first build in the queue and builds it.

Now let's do a timeline:

1. C is triggered, adds build C#1 to the queue and the build starts right away since there is nothing executing
2. A is triggered and adds build A1 to the queue, since the only executor is busy building C#1
3. Build C#1 is nearing its completion and at the end it triggers a build of D, build D#1. Build D#1 is put on the queue right after build A#1
4. Once C#1 finishes, the executor takes the next item in the queue, which happens to be A#1 (since it's been there the longest).
5. A#1 finishes as adds B#1 to the queue, right after D#1
6. D#1 is built since it is the first in the queue
7. Finally B#1 is built

So as you can se, the executor always takes the build that has been in the queue the longest. There are ways you can alter this priority, for example using the [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin), it allows you to set higher priority for certain jobs, in your case you should put higher priority on job B and D.

Comment: Yeah but I have four executors only one is running at any given time. I also tried using the upstream downstream job blocking too, still did not help.

Comment: Okay, that is strange, as I see jobs A and B are totally independent of jobs C and D, right? Then they should build independent of each other, strange... When c is building, is A in the queue? If it is, you should be able to se why it isn't building by going to job A's page and checking the build history.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, all four jobs are linked. When there is no SCM change the order is executing fine. The problem I noticed only happen when there is an SCM change in upstream or downstream job. SCM triggered Job taking precedence.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. My only guess is that the SCM triggered job get's into the queue before the other one, and hence will be built before the other.

Comment: Yeah because of this all jobs are out of order and waiting in the queue. Back to my original question, is this a bug or is there another way you can avoid this?

Comment: I would say that this is expected behaviour, the one longest in the queue is built first. But as I said in my answer, use priority sorter plugin to put different priority on the different jobs, D highest, then C, then B and A has lowest.